# html5 mp4 video on IE - path to file from AWS S3

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

I am having an issue playing video on IE.

When i have the path to the mp4 video is local such as this, it works:

```
<video poster="myVideo.png" preload="none" controls="controls">
    <source src="myVideo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src="myVideo.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
    <source src="myVideo.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
</video>
```

But if it's hosted on a URL path like this, IE does not play the video:

```
<video poster="https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets/myVideo.png" preload="none" controls="controls">
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets/myVideo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets/myVideo.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets/myVideo.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
</video>
```

What could be the problem?

---

## Fixed:

Ensure that, when you save your video file to S3, you must specify the `Content-Type`:

Also for IE's poster to appear, you'll need `preload="none"` inside the video tag:

[image: Set the Content-Type when you save to S3]

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or post a link to your project?  Which particular version of IE?

Comment: @Jrod im testing on IE9, the path exposes some info that i cant share at the moment but let me see if i can post to a different amazon account

Comment: I understand there maybe specific things you don't want to share but without seeing your particular case it is hard to say exactly what the issue is.  Try placing the path to the video file directly into the address bar in IE and see what happens.

Comment: @Jrod thank you,  on IE i get the option to download the file

Comment: Okay try two more things for me. 1) remove the quotes around the codec `<source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets/myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" />` and see if that works.  Failing that try 2) just use a simplified video tag and see if that plays `<video src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets/myVideo.mp4" controls></video>`

Comment: @Jrod 2) almost did it, i see the controllers up for a second then it disappears

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24198/discussion-between-t-q-and-jrod)